# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to update file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm in a beginner CS class and I'm trying to update info in a file. The info in the array does get replaced temporarily; however, I am unable to save the changes to the file. And, even after it's replaced, I get the "null" error.

Here is my code, I have omitted the lines and methods that are unrelated:

```
     public static void readData(){
    // Variables
    int choice2, location;

    // Read file
    File dataFile = new File("C:/Users/shirley/Documents/cddata.txt");
    FileReader in;
    BufferedReader readFile;

    // Arrays
    String[] code  = new String[100];
    String[] type = new String[100];
    String[] artist = new String[100];
    String[] song = new String[100];
    Double[] price = new Double[100];
    Double[] vSales = new Double[100];

    // Split Variables
    String tempCode, tempType, tempArtist, tempSong, tempPrice, tempVsales;

    // Split
    String text;
    int c = 0;

    try{
        in = new FileReader(dataFile);
        readFile = new BufferedReader(in);
        while ((text = readFile.readLine()) != null){
            // Split line into temp variables
            tempCode = text.substring(0,5);
            tempType = text.substring(5,15);
            tempArtist = text.substring(16,30);
            tempSong = text.substring(30,46);
            tempPrice = text.substring(46,52);
            tempVsales = text.substring(52);

            // Place text in correct arrays
            code[c] = tempCode;
            type[c] = tempType;
            artist[c] = tempArtist;
            song[c] = tempSong;
            price[c] = Double.parseDouble(tempPrice);
            vSales[c] = Double.parseDouble(tempVsales);

            c += 1; // increase counter
        }

        // Output to user
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nSelect another number: ");
        choice2 = kb.nextInt();

        // Reads data
        if (choice2 == 5){
            reqStatsSort(code,type,artist,song,price,vSales,c);
            location = reqStatistics(code,type,artist,song,price,vSales,c);
            if (location == -1){
                System.out.println("Sorry, code not found.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("Enter new volume sales: ");
                vSales[location] = kb.nextDouble();
            }
            displayBestSellerArray(type,artist,song,vSales,c);

            readFile.close();
            in.close();

            changeVolume(code,type,artist,song,price,vSales,c); // Method to rewrite file
            readData();
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File does not exist or could not be found.");
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}










/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////// REQ STATS SORT METHOD ////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void reqStatsSort(String[] sortCode, String[] sortType, String[] sortArtist, 
        String[] sortSong, Double[] sortPrice, Double[] sortVSales, int c){
    // Variables
    String tempCode, tempArtist, tempType, tempSong;
    double tempVsales, tempPrice;

    for(int j = 0; j < (c - 1); j++){
        for (int k = j + 1; k < c; k++){
            if ((sortCode[k]).compareToIgnoreCase(sortCode[j]) < 0){
                // Switch CODE
                tempCode = sortCode[k];
                sortCode[k] = sortCode[j];
                sortCode[j] = tempCode;

                // Switch TYPE
                tempType = sortType[k];
                sortType[k] = sortType[j];
                sortType[j] = tempType;

                // Switch ARTIST
                tempArtist = sortArtist[k];
                sortArtist[k] = sortArtist[j];
                sortArtist[j] = tempArtist;

                // Switch SONG
                tempSong = sortSong[k];
                sortSong[k] = sortSong[j];
                sortSong[j] = tempSong;

                // Switch VOLUME
                tempVsales = sortVSales[k];
                sortVSales[k] = sortVSales[j];
                sortVSales[j] = tempVsales;

                // Switch PRICE
                tempPrice = sortPrice[k];
                sortPrice[k] = sortPrice[j];
                sortPrice[j] = tempPrice; 
            }
        }

    }
}    










/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// REQUEST STATISTICS METHOD //////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static int reqStatistics(String[] statsCode, String[] statsType,
        String[] statsArtist, String[] statsSong, Double[] statsPrice, 
        Double[] statsVSales, int c){
    // Variables
    String cdCode;

    // Obtain input from user
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a CD code: ");
    cdCode = kb.nextLine();

    // Binary search
    int position;
    int lowerbound = 0;
    int upperbound = c - 1;

    // Find middle position
    position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;

    while((statsCode[position].compareToIgnoreCase(cdCode) != 0) && (lowerbound <= upperbound)){
        if((statsCode[position].compareToIgnoreCase(cdCode) > 0)){
            upperbound = position - 1;
        }
        else {
            lowerbound = position + 1;
        }
        position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
    }

    if (lowerbound <= upperbound){
        return(position);
    }
    else {
        return (-1);
    }
}











/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// BEST SELLER ARRAY METHOD //////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static void displayBestSellerArray (String[] displaySortedType, 
        String[] displaySortedArtist, String[] displaySortedSong, 
        Double[] displaySortedVSales, int c){
    // Output to user
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("MUSIC         ARTIST              HIT SONG            VOLUME");
    System.out.println("TYPE                                                  SALES");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        System.out.print(displaySortedType[i] + "   " + displaySortedArtist[i] + "     "
                + displaySortedSong[i] + "     ");
        System.out.format("%6.0f",displaySortedVSales[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}












/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// CHANGE VOLUME METHOD ////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void changeVolume(String[] writeCode, String[] writeType,
        String[] writeArtist, String[] writeSong, Double[] writePrice,
        Double[] writeVSales, int c){
    File textFile = new File("C:/Users/shirley/Documents/cddata.txt");
    FileWriter out;
    BufferedWriter writeFile;

    // Variables
    String entireRecord, tempVSales;
    int decLoc;

    try{
        out = new FileWriter(textFile);
        writeFile = new BufferedWriter(out);

        // Output to user
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++){
            // Convert volume sales to String
            tempVSales = Double.toString(writeVSales[i]);
            // Get rid of decimals
            decLoc = (tempVSales.indexOf("."));
            tempVSales = tempVSales.substring(0,decLoc);
            // Create record line
            entireRecord = writeCode[i] + " " + writeType[i] + " " + writeArtist[i]
                    + " " + writeSong[i] + " " + writePrice[i] + " " + tempVSales;
            // Write record to file
            writeFile.write(entireRecord);
            if (i != c){
                writeFile.newLine();
            }
        }
        writeFile.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Data written to file.");
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Problem writing to file.");
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The last method, changeVolume(), is what isn't working. The error I get is

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at culminating3.Culminating3.changeVolume(Culminating3.java:508)
at culminating3.Culminating3.readData(Culminating3.java:185)
at culminating3.Culminating3.readData(Culminating3.java:167)
at culminating3.Culminating3.main(Culminating3.java:47)
    Java Result: 1
```

Line 508 is:

```
                    tempVSales = Double.toString(writeVSales[i]);
```

in the changeVolume method().

So my program asks the user for a CD code to change the volume of sales, and sorts the arrays to perform a binary search if the inputted code exists. If it does, my program replaces the old volume of sales (which it does), and saves it with the changeVolume() method (which it doesn't do and gives me the error).

Please keep in mind I'm a newbie. It looks fine to me but I can't figure out why it's not working. I apologize for any messes in the code. writeVSales[] shouldn't be null because I assigned input in the readData() method?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
       // Convert volume sales to String
        tempVSales = Double.toString(writeVSales[i]);
        // Get rid of decimals
        decLoc = (tempVSales.indexOf("."));
        tempVSales = tempVSales.substring(0,decLoc);
```

I suggest you to take some sample values and work on this first.

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

When you input the information into the `writeVSales` array you start at `0` (good) and increment `c` everytime a new item is added, whether or not there is a new item to add or not (again this is fine).

```
int c = 0;

try{
    in = new FileReader(dataFile);
    readFile = new BufferedReader(in);
    while ((text = readFile.readLine()) != null){
        // Split line into temp variables
        tempCode = text.substring(0,5);
        tempType = text.substring(5,15);
        tempArtist = text.substring(16,30);
        tempSong = text.substring(30,46);
        tempPrice = text.substring(46,52);
        tempVsales = text.substring(52);

        // Place text in correct arrays
        code[c] = tempCode;
        type[c] = tempType;
        artist[c] = tempArtist;
        song[c] = tempSong;
        price[c] = Double.parseDouble(tempPrice);
        vSales[c] = Double.parseDouble(tempVsales);

        c += 1; // increase counter
    }
```

Later in `changeVolume()` your `for loop` starts at `1` and goes to `c`. So you are missing the first element and trying to add an element from an index that is `null`, hence the `NullPointerexception.

```
    // Output to user
    for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++){
        //code
    }
```

Change the `for loop` to start and `0` and go to `i < c` (i.e. `c - 1`):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        // Convert volume sales to String
        tempVSales = Double.toString(writeVSales[i]);
        // Get rid of decimals
        decLoc = (tempVSales.indexOf("."));
        tempVSales = tempVSales.substring(0,decLoc);
        // Create record line
        entireRecord = writeCode[i] + " " + writeType[i] + " " + writeArtist[i]
                + " " + writeSong[i] + " " + writePrice[i] + " " + tempVSales;
        // Write record to file
        writeFile.write(entireRecord);
        if (i != c){
            writeFile.newLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, wait,, I get another error when doing that. It says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9 35"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
 at culminating3.Culminating3.readData(Culminating3.java:118)
 at culminating3.Culminating3.readData(Culminating3.java:186)
 at culminating3.Culminating3.readData(Culminating3.java:143)
 at culminating3.Culminating3.main(Culminating3.java:47)
Java Result: 1

Comment: "9 35" isn't a double. You have a parsing problem.

Comment: What should the value be? If everything in the String is delimited by a whitespace, it would be less error prone in `readData()` to break the `String` up by the white space and using `text.split(" ")` and then assign the variables that way. It looks like you are getting the value of the `sales` and `price` in your second call to `readData()` because the substring for sales isn't the same size once you cut off the decimal in `changeVolume()`